# cut/copy file with it's related file/folders like html

Tags: windows, file, operating-system, copy, cut

I've a binary file with "dat" suffix and a json file which contains information about that file. Is there any way to cut/copy json file whenever .dat file cut/copied? (As you know .html file has a folder which contains it's css and gifs, ... when we copy the file, the folder also will be copied.)

my platform is windows 7.

Comment: (As you know .html file has a folder which contains it's css and gifs, ... when we copy the file, the folder also will be copied.) Those folders and files copied along the html files are the dependencies files and they are needed when the html file is executed. How is the json file related to your dat file?

Comment: @PaulNgom, my application parse the binary file with json file so I want to force users to always save binary file with json file.

Comment: Can you use `zip` file format for copying? The `zip` would contain both the `dat` file and the `json` file

Comment: You can join both files into one. Either always zip them so your application takes care for zipping/unzipping when it works with the content or google for multiparty/formdata. You will get a nice proposal how to combine different formats in one file. Otherwise I am afraid you cannot force copying a file along with another one